# how to show last 5 post in wordpress using this bootstrap grid codes?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to dynamically the following code written by Bootstrap 4 using the WordPress loop.
I want show the 5 last posts in the following code. like as the picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4fYa.jpg

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-md-stretch">
            <div class="jumbotron ">
                Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```php
<?php $posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 5)); ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-md-stretch">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <!-- Post 5 -->
                <?php echo $posts[4]->post_title; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <!-- Post 2 -->
                        <?php echo $posts[1]->post_title; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <!-- Post 1 -->
                        <?php echo $posts[0]->post_title; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <!-- Post 4 -->
                        <?php echo $posts[3]->post_title; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <!-- Post 3 -->
                        <?php echo $posts[2]->post_title; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```